# Using Disqus for a 'Single Sign-On' on a site

Tags: php, javascript, single-sign-on, disqus

So i'd like to be able to use Disqus to let people register for my site and at the same time disqus. Thus giving letting them not have to sign up twice but also having one profile on the site.

I was thinking when the post for the Disqus sign up is sent i could just hook into this and put these details into my database. Trouble is people won't know they are doing this.

I am also aware Disqus offer this service. For for $299 p/m this isn't a viable option.

Comment: closed and yet it has 1.7k views... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to write your own comments system that integrates with your own user system.

There are some free single sign-on solutions so you don't have to write all the code to authorize facebook, twitter etc it just goes through 1 API.

I personally use http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

Comment: Ye, i've already got my own comment system. But managing it becomes boring when i could also tie in SSO with my comments. So thanks for the link. These guys also do comments like disqus and SSO

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your question is, but you are correct in your statement, Disqus will only integrate the data you need for a single sign-on if you are a pro member or higher. This means having a paid account.

As a user of Disqus on a free account in a web app with over 1000 comments per day and also having a user profile system, I have noticed that users don't typically mind that they are separate. Once a user logs in to Disqus via twitter, Facebook or otherwise, they will stay logged in as long as they don't clear cookies.

Similarly you can make your sites user profile area have a lasting login so the user doesn't need to worry about it very often.  Once they login, they won't notice a difference.

A little more annoying? Sure is, but less annoying than paying $299/month to Disqus.

Comment: heh i'll certainly agree with this. Well what i'm after is a simple way to let users use disqus to log into my site and the comments system. but like you say if users really aren't fussed about signing into both then maybe its not that big an issue and i just look at other sso options for my site main.